# So.. since when is Microsoft recording all my SPOnline View interactions?

Tags: office-365, view

I have not been in this part of the SharePoint/Online HTML code for a while and have no time to read all the Office365 Roadmap updates

Since when is that `WriteDocEngagementLog` function in the View columnheader interaction??
(this is NOT the New Library View)

Is this only First Release?

[image]

And why do I feel the urge to run this in the console:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  WriteDocEngagementLog(...);
},1e5);
```

Comment: It has been live for a while now, it is part of the compliance and reporting features of Office 365, it is SharePoint auditing on steroids. You should see the Security and Compliance tile in the waffle, which handles the aggregation.

Comment: So many things to click.. you know.. the older I get the more I long for my Vic-20 and being 12 again.. I must be getting close to 50 and thus close to dead in the eyes of the Transpiler-Nerds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these are all related to the Compliance Center roll out, that shows as previously released on the roadmap, http://fasttrack.microsoft.com/roadmap.

> The Office 365 Compliance Center is one place to manage compliance
>   across Office 365 for your organization. You can define central
>   policies that apply across your data in Office 365, such as preserve
>   policies that keep content in SharePoint and Exchange indefinitely or
>   for a set time period. Links to existing SharePoint and Exchange
>   compliance features bring together the compliance capabilities across
>   Office 365.

The compliance center has a lot more auditing capabilities than previously available in SharePoint. See more information at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn876574.aspx.